# Attachement file deletion after sending out an email

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, unlink

In a larger project, have a form which uploads 2 files. I am using codeigniter as the framework. After the form upload it should send these 2 files as an email.

In order to attach it to an email, we should have a local copy of the file. Hence I move the files to a temporary folder and use the naming convention of [session-id]_my_file_1 and [session-id]_my_file_2

Finally after sending out the email I try to delete the these temporary files. But `unlink` is not deleting these files. I donot know the reason for this.

My guess is: It may be still being used by the mail command to upload/send. Below are the code outline I have written.

```
            $config['upload_path']      = './tmp_holder/';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'doc|docx|pdf|rtf';
        $config['max_size']         = '10240';
        $config['file_name']        = $this->session->userdata('session_id').'_1';
        $config['overwrite']        = TRUE;

        $config2['upload_path']     = './tmp_holder/';
        $config2['allowed_types']   = 'doc|docx|pdf|rtf';
        $config2['max_size']        = '10240';
        $config2['file_name']       = $this->session->userdata('session_id').'_2';
        $config2['overwrite']       = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('init_app_form');
        }
        else
        {

            if($this->upload->do_upload('cvFile') === FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('init_app_form');
            }
            else {
                $file1Return = $this->upload->data();

                $this->upload->initialize($config2);
                if($this->upload->do_upload('researchFile') === FALSE) {
                    $this->load->view('init_app_form');
                }
                else {
                    //process data here
                    $file2Return = $this->upload->data();

                    $this->config->load('email');

                    $this->email->initialize($this->config->item('email_conf'));


                    $this->email->from($this->config->item('email_from'), $this->input->post('tname').' '.$this->input->post('fname').' '.$this->input->post('lname'));
                    $this->email->to($this->config->item('email_to'));

                    $this->email->subject('something');
                    $this->email->message('something'); 

                    $this->email->attach($file1Return['full_path']);
                    $this->email->attach($file2Return['full_path']);

                    if( $this->email->send() == false ) {
                        //error
                        echo $this->email->print_debugger(); exit;
                    }

                    $this->email->clear();
                                    ////////////////////////////////
                    @unlink($this->session->userdata('session_id').'_2');
                                    ////////////////////////////////
                    $this->load->view('init_app_success');
                }
                                   ////////////////////////////////
                @unlink($this->session->userdata('session_id').'_1');
                                   ////////////////////////////////
            }

        }
```

The Solution I did was to delete the files in the temp folder before I do this so that previous files are cleared. But this is not a clean approach right? This is because:

1. It may be trying deleting other files currently being used by other parallel instances
2. I want the tmp folder to be empty after I send itself.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use file_helper which is in code igniter.

```
$this->load->helper("file");
delete_files($this->session->userdata('session_id').'_1');
```

[here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html) is documentation for this

Comment: "Deletes ALL files contained in the supplied path" It doesnt answer my specific problem. And this is the solution I mentioned which has the problem 1 mentioned.

Comment: if you put there file path it will delete only the file not whole folder. So you have to call it twice with each file name.